# Packing bytes manually to send on network

Tags: c#, serialization, bit-manipulation

I have an object that has the following variables:

```
bool firstBool;  
float firstFloat; (0.0 to 1.0)  
float secondFloat (0.0 to 1.0)  
int firstInt; (0 to 10,000)
```

I was using a ToString method to get a string that I can send over the network. Scaling up I have encountered issues with the amount of data this is taking up.
the string looks like this at the moment: 
`"false:1.0:1.0:10000"` this is 19 characters at 2 bytes per so 38 bytes

I know that I can save on this size by manually storing the data in 4 bytes like this:

```
A|B|B|B|B|B|B|B  
C|C|C|C|C|C|C|D  
D|D|D|D|D|D|D|D  
D|D|D|D|D|X|X|X  

A = bool(0 or 1), B = int(0 to 128), C = int(0 to 128), D = int(0 to 16384), X = Leftover bits
```

- I convert the `float(0.0 to 1.0)` to `int(0 to 128)` since I can rebuild them on the other end and the accuracy isn't super important.

I have been experimenting with BitArray and byte[] to convert the data into and out of the binary structure.

After some experiments I ended up with this serialization process(I know it needs to be cleaned up and optimized)

```
public byte[] Serialize() {
    byte[] firstFloatBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(Mathf.FloorToInt(firstFloat * 128)); //Convert the float to int from (0 to 128)

    byte[] secondFloatBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(Mathf.FloorToInt(secondFloat * 128)); //Convert the float to int from (0 to 128)

    byte[] firstIntData = BitConverter.GetBytes(Mathf.FloorToInt(firstInt)); // Get the bytes for the int

    BitArray data = new BitArray(32); // create the size 32 bitarray to hold all the data

    int i = 0; // create the index value

    data[i] = firstBool; // set the 0 bit

    BitArray ffBits = new BitArray(firstFloatBytes);
    for(i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
        data[i] = ffBits[i-1]; // Set bits 1 to 7
    }

    BitArray sfBits = new BitArray(secondFloatBytes);
    for(i = 8; i < 15; i++) {
        data[i] = sfBits[i-8]; // Set bits 8 to 14
    }

    BitArray fiBits = new BitArray(firstIntData);
    for(i = 15; i < 29; i++) {
        data[i] = fiBits[i-15]; // Set bits 15 to 28
    }
    byte[] output = new byte[4]; // create a byte[] to hold the output
    data.CopyTo(output,0); // Copy the bits to the byte[]
    return output;
}
```

Getting the information back out of this structure is much more complicated than getting it into this form. I figure I can probably workout something using the bitwise operators and bitmasks.

This is proving to be more complicated than I was expecting. I thought it would be very easy to access the bits of a byte[] to manipulate the data directly, extract ranges of bits, then convert back to the values required to rebuild the object. Are there best practices for this type of data serialization? Does anyone know of a tutorial or example reference I could read?

Comment: You are making it much harder than you need to.  First put D into a int16 simply using BitConverter.Getbytes(D).  Then put C into a byte using BitConverter.GetBytes(C),

Comment: That does make sense since it would be 9 bytes which is much better than what I have right now. It's also easy enough to get up and running. My intent with attempting to pack it tighter, is that my spec has some tight requirements on bandwidth so I figured going as small as I can now will save me time later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple method for pack/unpack.  But you loose accuracy converting a float to only 7/8 bits

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            foreach (Data data in Data.input)
            {
                Data.Print(data);
                Data results = Data.Unpack(Data.Pack(data));
                Data.Print(results);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    public class Data
    {
        public static List<Data> input = new List<Data>() {
            new Data() { firstBool = true, firstFloat = 0.2345F, secondFloat = 0.432F,   firstInt = 12},
            new Data() { firstBool = true, firstFloat = 0.3445F, secondFloat = 0.432F,   firstInt = 11},
            new Data() { firstBool = false, firstFloat = 0.2365F, secondFloat = 0.432F,   firstInt = 9},
            new Data() { firstBool = false, firstFloat = 0.545F, secondFloat = 0.432F,   firstInt = 8},
            new Data() { firstBool = true, firstFloat = 0.2367F, secondFloat = 0.432F,   firstInt = 7}
        };


        public bool firstBool { get; set; }
        public float firstFloat {get; set; } //(0.0 to 1.0)  
        public float secondFloat {get; set; } //(0.0 to 1.0)  
        public int firstInt { get; set; } //(0 to 10,000)

        public static byte[] Pack(Data data)
        {
            byte[] results = new byte[4];

            results[0] = (byte)((data.firstBool ? 0x80 : 0x00) | (byte)(data.firstFloat * 128));
            results[1] = (byte)(data.secondFloat * 256);
            results[2] = (byte)((data.firstInt >> 8) & 0xFF);
            results[3] = (byte)(data.firstInt & 0xFF);

            return results;
        }
        public static Data Unpack(byte[] data)
        {
            Data results = new Data();

            results.firstBool = ((data[0] & 0x80) == 0) ? false : true;
            results.firstFloat = ((float)(data[0] & 0x7F)) / 128.0F;
            results.secondFloat = (float)data[1] / 256.0F;
            results.firstInt = (data[2] << 8) | data[3];

            return results;
        }
        public static void Print(Data data)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Bool : '{0}', 1st Float : '{1}', 2nd Float : '{2}', Int : '{3}'",
                data.firstBool,
                data.firstFloat,
                data.secondFloat,
                data.firstInt
                );


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: An example of packing a byte[] is exactly what I was looking for. I have a bunch of other network messages that I need to pack and I can use this as a model for them. Thanks again!

Comment: I can get better accuracy on floating number if I use the float mantissa values which are logarithmic rather than a linear divide.

Comment: When you say that, do you mean that you can pack the float's mantissa since the values are between 0 and 1 since the sign, and power are not needed for values of this size?

Comment: I feel smart today! Thanks again for the insight.

Answer (score 3):

Standard and efficient serialization methods are:

1. Using `BinaryWriter` / `BinaryReader`:

   ```
   public byte[] Serialize()
   {
      using(var s = new MemoryStream())
      using(var w = new BinaryWriter(s))
      {
         w.Write(firstBool);
         w.Write(firstFloat);
         ...
         return s.ToArray();
      }
   }

   public void Deserialize(byte[] bytes)
   {
      using(var s = new MemoryStream(bytes))
      using(var r = new BinaryReader(s))
      {
         firstBool = r.ReadBool();
         firstFload = r.ReadFloat();
         ...
      }
   }
   ```
2. Using [protobuf.net](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/642677/Protobuf-net-the-unofficial-manual)

`BinaryWriter` / `BinaryReader` is much faster (around 7 times). Protobuf is more flexible, easy to use, very popular and serializes into around 33% fewer bytes. (of course these numbers are orders of magnitude and depend on what you serialize and how).

Now basically `BinaryWriter` will write 1 + 4 + 4 + 4 = 13 bytes. You shrink it to 5 bytes by converting the values to bool, byte, byte, short first by rounding it the way you want. Finally it's easy to merge the bool with one of your bytes to get 4 bytes if you really want to.

I don't really discourage manual serialization. But it has to be worth the price in terms of performance. The code is quite unreadable. Use bit masks and binary shifts on bytes directly but keep it as simple as possible. Don't use BitArray. It's slow and not more readable.